# Image rules always returns error in Laravel

Tags: image, validation, laravel-5, rules

I have an array of data as below :

```
array:2 [▼
  "pg_location_id" => 10
  "image_location" => "pg_images/2017/10/pg-90d7e835d382a91d1635403f17b6fa76.jpg"
]
```

and the `rules` is :

```
public static $rules = [
        'pg_location_id'    =>  'required|exists:pg_locations,id',
        'image_location'    =>  'required|image|max:500',
    ];
```

An my controller where I am trying to insert image(s) is :

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {

                for($i = 0; $i < count($request->image); $i++) {
                    if ($request->file('image')[$i]->isValid()) {
                        $fileName = 'pg-'.md5(uniqid()).'.'.$request->file('image')[$i]->getClientOriginalExtension();
                        $request->file('image')[$i]->move($destination_path, $fileName);
                        $img_data['image_location'] = 'pg_images/'.date('Y').'/'.$pg_location->id.'/'.$fileName;

                        $validator = Validator::make($img_data, PgLocationImage::$rules);
                        if ($validator->fails()) return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator);
                        PgLocationImage::create( $img_data );
                    }
                }
            }
```

But it always says

> The image location must be an image

Answer (score 1):

for image rule you must pass file variable but you pass a simple string variable.
first check in your controller, at the first line print as follow:

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    dd($requesti->hasFile('image_location'));
    $rules = [];
    ......
}
```

If there is file then it will return true else you can't pass a file variable in request.